How to run Azure logic apps in Visual Studio 2019 or Visual Studio 2022?
I am trying to create Azure Logic app in Visual Studio.
I did create an Azure Resource Group project.
Then selected Logic apps as the template and project is created. After that, when I try to open the LogicApp.json using 'Open with Logic app Designer' as shown below, it doesn't show me that option.
Expected:

Actual:

What should I do to move ahead?
Reference link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-logic-apps-with-visual-studio


'Open with Logic app Designer' as shown below, it doesn't show me that option.

It is changed, If you are using VS 2019 then only you can get Logic app designer using below steps and I followed Microsoft-Document:

Click On View.
Then click on Cloud Explorer as below:


Then download and install Azure Logic Apps Tools:


Now you can edit like below:

Then you can use Logic App Designer:

If you want to create and open new one then click open with(after installing the Azure Logic Apps Tools) :

In VS 2019, you can edit and run logic apps using this feature.
In VS2022, AFAIK, there is no cloud explorer so, i think one cannot edit using designer.
